# Did Muslims in the Middle East cut off the breasts of Christian women?

Tags: criminology, islam, violence, christianity

A [Conservative Infidel](http://www.conservativeinfidel.com/warning-graphic-content-muslims-take-christian-girls-cut-breasts/) article from 2014 made a claim (that was repeated in a forum for [Americans for Legal Immigration PAC](http://www.alipac.us/f19/warning-graphic-content-muslims-take-christian-girls-cut-their-breasts-off-311024/)) that:

> Muslims in the Middle East took Christian girls and cut their breasts off. Sister Hatune Dogan interviewed 280 girls and said that a number of them suffered this sort of mutilation, alongside rape and lacerations with blades.

The report seems to be based on [an article by Katie Yoder](http://newsbusters.org/blogs/katie-yoder/2014/09/15/nuns-slam-media-silence-middle-east-christian-persecution), which doesn't seem to identify the victims, their ages, the location or the times.

The article shows two photos showing atrocities against unidentified girls. The second photo (the one that shows a girl with her breasts cut of) was reported by https://hinduexistence.org/tamil-hindu-killing-fields-in-sri-lanka/ in 2012 claiming to show rape and sexual violence perpetrated by Sri Lankan armed forces against Tamils. Which claim is true?

**(Graphic warning content on all links)**

Comment: The fact that the only sites that I see claiming this is true are reactionary, right-wing sites like islamevseurope.com and jihadwatch leads me to think that there are not going to be reliable sources.  Generally, if an article doesn't mention details, that's a good sign (although, in this case, I would expect victim names to be withheld if it was true).  The nun you mention also has claimed that Muslims are selling vials of Christian blood for $100,000 on the black market.

Comment: @rougon: And to think a lot of us give blood for free. Of course I'm not a Christian, but for $100K/vial, I'm willing to lie about that :-)

Comment: @KDog Where do people regularly practice those acts on a scale large enough to stand in for the whole society?  It seems like you are taking selective events from across a vast region and putting them together.  If you took all of the nasty things the US or Europe does, we would look demonic too.

Comment: Extremely graphic, extreme warning http://www.n2hr.com/vb/t22126.html I found a more complete set of photos of the woman with breasts cut off on an Arabic site, but I haven't translated yet.  This has nothing to do with the girls in the story of the OP who were still alive.

Comment: @DavePhD I found a link older than yours (2009) http://www.ly2l.org/vb/t46853.html

Comment: @KDog "In societies that practice regularly Cliterectomies, honor killings, raping of young boys at the age of 5, stonings, advocate the marriage age of girls at 9, honor killings, beheadings, and the leaders engage in torture and use chemical weapons against their own populations, is this really that much of a stretch?" 

How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Disgusting, but unrelated to the actual story of the kidnapped girls who were released after ransom payment. They're still alive, and obviously she isn't.  People seem to stick unrelated photos in articles often now. Very irresponsible.

Comment: @DavePhD I'm not sure what that picture is supposed to be. Both the one that shows up in the links in this question and the extra related ones you found are all heavily photoshopped — but it's not clear *why*. Perhaps there were other things nearby in the scene or watermarks than somebody tried to remove, but all the views have weird bits that have been edited with bits of background slapped on top of foreground objects. Whatever horrendous acts this depicts, the reporting at least is clearly dishonest in some fashion.

Comment: @Caleb I think with any news story these days, even from legitimate news organizations, they are constantly sticking in file-photos that aren't of the actual events in the story.  Unless a caption specifically says it is a photo of the actual events in the story, I just assume it isn't.

Comment: @DavePhD "I think with any news story these days, even from legitimate news organizations,  they are constantly sticking in file-photos that aren't of the actual events in the story." They generally add the details of the photo below it in a caption. But the story cited doesn't say anything about it. So, by default, it would be regarded as something related to the story.

Comment: @Caleb I thought it was doctored and that's why I asked it. :-D

Comment: I found why it was photoshopped so heavily. As I guessed in my earlier comment the source image had something on it that they edited out. [This page from Dec 2007](http://www.al-7up.com/vb/t8044.html) has the same images with a big attribution that somebody tried to erase and just did a bad job of replacing bits of the image.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin like the front page picture of the boy here: http://www.aljazeera.com/ (at the moment) with no caption.  Is he really related to the intensification of the bombing of Aleppo?

Comment: @DavePhD In that case yes it does. Check [the article](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2016/11/battle-aleppo-syria-army-intensifies-air-campaign-161118090027663.html) for details. I get what you're saying — and yes it happens far too much (and in the case of the question has obviously been abused) but don't just throw out random examples that don't stand up to scrutiny yourself.

Comment: Found a link that says the girl is from Jordan and was found dead. http://vb.n4hr.com/101594.html

Comment: @mohammad goes to plausibility

Answer (score 2):

[An Interview With Sister Hatune Dogan](http://gatesofvienna.net/2014/06/an-interview-with-sister-hatune-dogan/)

transcript:

> Q:   What did these girls tell you?
>
> A:   These girls…
>
> Q:   What did they experience?
>
> A:   It is horrible. I cannot explain everything but these 218 girls under [their breath] they told me that what had happened to them: they [the perpetrators] raped them, they cut some portions of them — a sample — from this number that I spoke [to], 13 of them, they cut half of the vagina. I saw it with my own eyes. How many there are that I didn’t see, I don’t know. Three, they cut their breast, only because they [the abductors] were not happy with the ransom. All of them, they had to pay ransom to come to be freed. [If] they were not happy with that, some of them, they cut their faces.
>
> I have photos, I have much […], I have video, I have everything there [to prove this]. I have all these girls, the youngest one I had to cry on her shoulder. Others cried on my shoulder. And I have feelings for these girls. These traumatic views, they’ll never go from my brain, from my mind. I am psychologically normally [strong], but through the power of my Lord, through my psychological knowledge, through my Bible I can pass over these heavy things till today.

So according to witness testimony, the breasts were cut, but not cut "off".

(The photos in the OP article have nothing to do with the actual girls who were cut)

Also, the girls were not necessarily Christian.

According to [Yazidi refugees in Germany find shelter at the home of a nun](http://www.i24news.tv/en/news/international/europe/117322-160620-yazidi-refugees-seek-refuge-with-nuns-in-germany)

> she encountered 218 Christian and Yazidi rape victims. “The youngest was five and a half years old when they raped her. I met her two years later and she still couldn't speak one word because she was traumatized.” Some of these girls were mutilated, she says, because the kidnappers weren't happy with the ransom.

Comment: Have journalists or prosecutors validated those pictures and videos?

Comment: This is just a repeat of the original claim, using a less than reputable source, which in turn refers to the same source as the article of the OP (a nun which seems to be rather biased on the topic of islam).

Comment: @tim no, this makes clear that the breast were not cut "off"

Comment: @DavePhD Thanks for the clarifying edit. This does seem to make it clear that OPs source exaggerated claims made by a biased nun which may or may not be true. I wouldn't call this interview "witness testimony", and I wouldn't consider it prove of anything else though.

Comment: @tim actually, I might have to change my answer, because a different video has captions "4:08 She and her sister were kidnapped, 4:12   kept in one room for months, being raped, 4:16   and finally got her left breast cut off, like the other girl, 4:20 because they were not satisfied with the ransom money.4:24 I’ve spoken to 218 girls in total who had been 4:28   kidnapped, raped and bought free. 4:32   Thirteen of them had their labia cut off, 4:36   three had a breast cut off." http://gatesofvienna.net/2013/12/december-10th-the-day-of-genuine-human-rights/ Matter of translation from German.

Comment: @DavePhD actually, gatesofvienna.net (not a credible source in my opinion) mistranslates the video. At 4:16 and 4:36 it says "geschnitten", which means "cut", not "cut off". But again, Hatune Dogan really isn't a credible source either. She also claimed that Muslims sell vials of Christian blood, and that ISIS is the same as all of Islam. Because of her extremely biased views she is commonly cited by far-right wing radicals and rarely by mainstream news outlets.

Comment: @tim Thanks for the translation.  As far as blood, she said someone with "severe psychological problems" told her that.  She's just relaying what that one person told her.

Comment: @tim That is correct, she said "geschnitten", but her German is quite broken. She could easily have meant "abgeschnitten". It is possible that she reported elsewhere in Turkish, her native language, and said "cut off". I don't think this German interview helps much.

Comment: @daraos what German word did she use for cutting the labia?

Comment: @DavePhD "13 davon haben die gesamte Schamlippe geschnitten" = "13 of them have the whole labia cut." This is translated literally. It really is not clear what she means, it's not a correct German sentence. The word "gesamte" = "whole" could indicate that they were cut off. But "geschnitten" is not "cut off". I'm a native German speaker and cannot understand what she really means.

Comment: I spent the last 45 minutes reading articles about Yazidian "ISIS sex-slaves" and listening to eye witness tapes. First off: I could not find a victim telling about "cut off" or "cut" breasts or labia. Of course that doesn't prove it has not been done. Second: the Yazidis are not Christian, but make up the majority of "sex slaves". I could not find a report in German articles about Yazidis that support this claim. Third: After spending 45 minutes on this, I just want to stop and do something fun instead.

Comment: @daraos this woman had her breast cut, http://www.friatider.se/taharrush-victim-nathalie-29-they-shouted-swedish-whore-and-cut-my-breast-razer-blade , but she's not one of the women OP is discussing

Comment: @tim in fairness, if she really *had* witnessed these things, I'd have some sympathy for her being extremely biased!